# Доречність лапок у виразах з прямим значенням

Tags: пунктуація

На одному новинному сайті є стаття "У Солсбері почали “очищення” території, пов’язаної з отруєнням Скрипалів". За нормами [Правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm), основні правила вживання лапок такі:
У лапки беруться:

> 1. Цитати, причому й тоді, коли цитата входить у середину речення як його складова частина:
>
> ...Усім нам, працівникам галузі перекладу, цього «високого мистецтва»,
>   за виразом К. І. Чуковського, або «благородного ремесла», як говорить
>   Марія Домбровська, корисно пам’ятати слова О. Твардовського про С.
>   Маршака як перекладача Бернса: «Він зробив його росіянином, залишивши
>   шотландцем». Я б додав ще: «Він зробив його Маршаком, залишивши
>   Бернсом», — бо ж не сама тільки печать національності, а й печать
>   індивідуальності лежить на кожному талановитому перекладі (Рильський).
>
> 2. Слова, що їх не вважають за свої або що наводяться з відтінком презирливого чи іронічного /181/ ставлення до чужого вислову, а також
>      слова, вжиті вперше або, навпаки, застарілі та незвичайні:
>
> Для більшості її [Лесі Українки] сучасників той дух [новаторського
>   мистецтва] нагадував «хмару, що сунулась так тяжко по долині», а для
>   нас, «на високості» XX століття, він «одмінився, просвічений нагірним,
>   чистим світлом» (Павличко).
>
> Моє ім’я враз із кількома іменами подібних до мене «во время оно»
>   оббігало весь край, було пострахом усіх «мирних і вірноконституційних
>   горожан», — з моїм іменем усі вони в’язали поняття перевороту,
>   революції, різні (Франко).
>
> 3. Індивідуальні назви заводів, фабрик, клубів, пароплавів, організацій, підприємств, наукових праць, літературних творів, газет,
>      журналів, кінофільмів тощо

З наведених правил, слово очищення має бути в лапках, якщо відповідає умовам п.2. Та ознак цього я в статті не знайшла. То за яким принципом воно узяте в лапки?

Comment: Як на мене тут лапки натякають на те що цей новинний сайт вважає що отруєння не було, тому "очищення" буде удаваним.

Comment: А можливо це цитата з одного слова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формально автори могли б спробувати виправдати лапки тим, що вони, мовляв, цитують джерело. Адже [informator.news](//informator.news/u-solsberi-pochaly-ochyschennya-terytoriji-pov-yazanoji-z-otrujennyam-skrypaliv/) (де опублікована наведена статтю) посилається на [Sky News](//news.sky.com/story/army-trucks-arrive-to-start-clean-up-in-salisbury-after-skripal-poisoning-11344435) («про це повідомляє Sky News»), а там (у першоджерелі — Sky News) це названо словом *clean-up*.

Але реально це дуже невдалий вжиток розділових знаків. Адже лапки мають різні значення: цитування чогось і недовіра/скептицизм/сумнів щодо чогось (мовляв, треба читати навпаки). І в даному контексті вони (лапки), принаймні особисто мною, сприймаються тільки як друге.

Це, звісно, якщо виключити можливість того, що автори дійсно (свідомо чи підсвідомо) хотіли висловити скептицизм, що це очищення. Якщо ж не виключати таку можливість, а навпаки припустити, що автори вважають це не очищенням, а імітацією, то тоді лапки вжиті доречно. Але, по-моєму, це контрастує з тоном решти статті, тому, по-моєму, це радше все-таки пунктуаційна помилка (або ж позиція безпоседнього автора відрізняється від офіційної позиції сайту новин і він підсвідомо висловив свою позицію — але відрізнити це від чистої помилки неможливо).

Comment: Доповню (на окрему відповідь мій коментар не тягне; якщо включите це у відповідь, я потім приберу коментар). Діяльність зі знезараження обʼєктів називається [***Deactivation** (of hazardous chemical wastes)*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/es00133a604?journalCode=esthag). Вжите слово *„clean-up”*, НМД, має виражену неформальну конотацію. А автор перекладу, НМД, дуже влучно це помітив і вказав його у лапках — саме з метою скептицизм/захоплення/подив + привернення уваги читача + напевно, щоб при передруку інші джерела не втратили це словечко. НМД. усе дуже слушно зроблено.

Comment: @bytebuster, мені здається, це мало б сенс, якби «clean-up» було реальною (або офіційною, або поширеною розмовною) назвою тієї операції. Але, наскільки я можу судити, в різних джерелах її називають по-різному, а «clean-up» (без лапок) пише просто конкретне джерело — в такому випадку немає чого зберігати (бо не посадова особа вжила це слово, а один із безлічі сайтів новин). Але, можливо, я неправильно Вас зрозумів.